# How to count unique requests in Grails?

Tags: spring, servlets, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Given a controller action test() as defined below. I can access the request and get the IP as well as the user agent. I want to count the number of requests that access test(). This is easy, I would just increase a counter on every request.

My question is how can I count the unique requests? I.e., I want to count a request coming from the same computer only once. Is there another way than storing all the ip addresses and user agents to see if they already occurred?

```
def test() {
  println "ip: "+request.getRemoteAddr()
  println "user agent: "+request.getHeader("User-Agent")

}
```

Comment: It seems like the obvious solution for this is to create a domain or add a collection onto an existing domain. Is that something you considered and didn't implement for a reason?

Comment: @JamesKleeh Is this the only way to save each request ip and user agent? It will cost a lot of data base space.

Comment: It depends on what you need to be able to do with this count.  If it needs to persist over long periods of time and survive restarts etc., then you need to persist the info somewhere like a database.  If it is more transient than then you might want to do something like have a singleton Spring bean which keeps track of IPs and associates a count with them and then write a simple filter which recognizes qualifying requests and updates the bean accordingly.

Comment: If you don't really need to keep track of them globally and just need to access the count from within a session then having a filter interacting with the session could be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new domain class as:

```
class RequestCount {
   String ip
   String userAgent
}
```

Then save a new object on each request. Count the number of unique entries and your are done.